# updating/cleaning up unnecessary "user account" data

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

SYSTEM INFO:
MS Windows XP Professional
Version 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600

System Model    Dell OptiPlex GX270
System Type X86-based PC
Processor   x86 Family 15 Model 2 Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~2793 Mhz
BIOS Version/Date   Dell Computer Corporation A06, 9/29/2004
SMBIOS Version  2.3
Total Physical Memory   1,024.00 MB
Total Virtual Memory    2.00 GB
Internal HDs:           c (80G) + f (40G)

QUESTION:
I would like to edit my administrator user account name, safely delete unused user accounts with their D&S files, and establish a new "guest" user account -- all without locking myself out of my own PC.

1) I have and am the sole user of the orignal administrator user account.
I would like to change the user name of this admin acct but keep the password.
How can this be done safely?

2) I don't have a "guest user" account.
I would like to create one.
How do I safely do this.

3) I have two older "user accounts" that I don't need.
How can I safely delete them and their D&S info while leaving my administrator and guest accounts operational.

4) Considering the above, in which order should I do these?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider breaking this up into multiple questions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of profile info in one step, Microsoft provides a user profile deletion tool [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=901A9B95-6063-4462-8150-360394E98E1E&displaylang=en).

For a more manual process:

1. While logged in as administrator, start in the Control Panel > Users app.  You should be able to remove the user accounts that are no longer needed and add the guest account.
2. Next, delete the user profile located in C:\Documents and Settings\username.  That should remove the data associated with that account.
3. I'd recommend doing a disk cleanup and defrag after that, just as a last maintenance step.

Comment: Deleting the account in user control won't delete the docs and settings folders you'll have to do that manually afterwards.

Comment: Good call, I was going to add that in an edit.  Thanks.